# MATLAB: Making a video using writeVideo

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am currently trying to make a video using the writeVideo function in MATLAB. I have made a GUI using GUIDE which includes a slider, a few checkboxs, and a single axes (tagged as axes1). When I move the slider, the axes will plot certain shapes that change according to the slider value.

What I am trying to do is record a video of the GUI being used to show the functionality in a presentation. However, when I play back the video (after making it using writeVideo), it shows the slider value moving and the checkboxes being checked correctly, but the plot never changes (i.e. it will only show the original shape). This seems to be some refresh error, however, anything I have tried has not worked (refresh, drawnow, etc.)

Any idea why this is happening? The following is the code I am trying to implement:

```
vidObj = VideoWriter('test.avi','Motion JPEG AVI');
open(vidObj);
flag = 0;
if flag<12 %movie will be 12 frames long
    flag = flag+1;
    if slider<1  
        plot something...
    elseif slider>=1 && slider<2
        plot something else...
    etc...
    elseif slider<=5
        plot something else...
    end

    hFigure = findobj('Name','gui');
    currFrame = getframe(hFigure);
    writeVideo(vidObj,currFrame);

    clear hfigure currFrame image;
else
    fprintf('done\n')
    close(vidObj);   
end
```

As stated, I can then use implay to play back the test.avi file, however, the plot never updates.

Thanks in advance

Note: I am using MATLAB R2012b

EDIT:

The following is how I ended up creating my video: maybe this will help someone who was facing similar issues to the one stated above.

I basically gave up on using getframe and decided to 1) get screenshots, then 2) turn the screenshots into a movie. To get the screenshots, I first ran my program then, in the command window, invoked the following code using the java toolkit

```
i = 1;
while true
    robo = java.awt.Robot;
    t = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

    %# Set screen size
    rectangle = java.awt.Rectangle(0,0,1000,640);

    %# Get the capture
    image = robo.createScreenCapture(rectangle);

    %# Save it to file
    filehandle = java.io.File(sprintf('capture%d.jpg', i));
    javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(image,'jpg',filehandle);

    pause(.4) %# Wait for 0.4 seconds
    i = i + 1;
end
```

This then continually ran in the background and took snap shots of the screen and stored them into the current directory. to stop it from running, just use Ctrl C. Once I had the screen shots, I used the following code to create the movie:

```
vidObj = VideoWriter('test.avi','Motion JPEG AVI');
open(vidObj);
for i=7:87 %these are the frames I wanted in my movie
    x = num2str(i);
    im = horzcat('capture',x);
    im1 = horzcat(im,'.jpg')
    imdata = imread(im1);
    writeVideo(vidObj,imdata);
end
close(vidObj);
```

Comment: Have you tried to `pause` for some time at each iteration?

Comment: Why do you have to do `clear` each time? What is your image variable? Notice there is a build-in MATLAB `image` function.

Comment: Hi yuk, Thanks for your input. Unfortunately, I have tried both drawnow and pause (for up to 5 seconds) and it has not worked. To be more specific, the GUI works as intended, but for whatever reason when I use getframe, it always shows the initialized plot and not the 'new' plot. In the code, I am telling it to getframe the entire GUI (cleverly named gui), and not solely the axes/plot. I am not sure why it is doing this, as I am already clearing the variables after each iteration to try and get the 'new' getframe.

Comment: I don't know if there is some internal issue with the writeVideo command which causes this plot updating error, or if I am simply overlooking something

Comment: I tried using clear to make sure that my variable currFrame was actually getting the updated frame and not simply showing the initialized frame. Also, I am aware that image is a function. please disregard the clearing of the image variable in the above code; I was using that show (imshow) the currFrame while working through the code for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

getframe is sometimes problematic. I'm not sure I can give an answer, and I can't simply comment because of my reputation, but this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719138/in-matlab-writing-images-to-avi-without-displaying-using-videowriter/15184319#15184319)  might be of help. After you get the figure from the GUI, turn it into an image and then into a frame. Worth a shot.

Comment: Hi Ne_Plus_Ultra, I have tried using the hardcopy function and youre right, it is worth looking into. However, it seems to give me the exact opposite result: it now updates the plot, but it now does not show the slider or checkboxes. Furthermore, I have my shapes as transparent and this method gets rid of the transparency which is not ideal.

Seems odd that this issue would give me such grief, as it initially seemed like it would be easy to create a video of me using this application with MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your monitor settings to 16 bit color it will solve the problem you are having. This has been documented on the link provided. My previous answer was deleted because I only supplied the link and told you how to solve the problem (sorry) but if you actually click on the link and see what they say or change your monitor settings to 16 bit color everything will work. From the link you can see that people have had this problem since 2009 but it was updated in april 2013 so it is still a problem and changing your monitor settings to 16 bit color is still a solution.

Hope this helps!

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/257389